# rsync --dry-run paged output - how to achieve?

Tags: command-line, rsync

I am syncing two large folders from local pc to remote server and the output from the --dry-run is several pages long, too long for terminal reading.

What is the syntax to add the directive `>>foo` to:

```
sudo /usr/bin/rsync -avx --delete --append-verify [source] [destination]
```

This will enable me to use the `more` command to read the file in pages.

I need this because of the error:

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to log to a file and echo to the screen to a pager.

`sudo /usr/bin/rsync -avx --delete --append-verify [source] [destination] 2>&1 | tee -a logfile.txt | less`

You'll get the output saved to `logfile.txt` and it will also appear in your terminal, using `less` as a pager.

Answer (score 2):

The rsync errors you said you want to include together in your log file are being sent to standard error. A Linux process has a standard input, standard output, and standard error, but the normal shell redirect only affects the standard output. `rsync` uses this for errors as it should. You can combine the two streams using `2>&1` after your redirection. `>>` means append, while `>` truncates the file, so I will append like you wish. Your command would be:

```bash
sudo /usr/bin/rsync -avx --delete --append-verify --dry-run [source] [destination] >> foo 2>&1
```

Then you can page the file with `less foo`.

Comment: If OP is **only** interested in stderr i.e. error messages, then `2>&1 1>/dev/null` instead of just `2>&1` will discard the stdout leaving only stderr